# Would a higher than recommend spec SD card work just as efficiently?

Tags: sd-card

My phone manufacturer recommends a class 10 sd card. At the time my phone came out, **UHS Speed Class: U1** and **Video Speed Class: V10** was the latest class 10 sd card.

However now there's [V90](https://www.sdcard.org/consumers/choices/speed_class/img/video_speed%20class_01.jpg). But since V90 is still classified as class 10 (as far as I know), would it be compatible with my phone? Would it work just as efficiently as the class 10 version that was available at the time my phone came out? Would the higher write/read capacity of the newer SD technology cause any hiccups? Or is it going to be
where it would only be a case of it not being used to it's full potential?

Phone: Motorola C Plus.

Comment: Micro SD cards are totally backwards compatible regarding their speed classes. Note if you want to use it as adoptable storage you should better search for the A1 standard and make sure to only buy a genuine card from a big known manufacturer. Cheap Chinese cards from unknown vendors often don't last very long in this scenario. And the most important: Before ever using a new micro-sd card in an Android device test it to really has the capacity it claims to have. This can be done using tools like H2testw, FakeFlashTest or  Flash Drive/Card Tester.